# Why service is still running if its process is killed?

Tags: android, process, android-service

I've checked, through decompilation, that in the manifest of some applications a service is not started with a separate process. By the way, in the task manager, it appears as "running".

For example Facebook, on Android 4.4.2, has got 0 processes and 2 services running.
From the documentation (and correct me if I'm wrong) I've understood that a Service runs in the same process of its Application. If the process dies, the service is stopped (and can be restarted automatically by an AlarmManager or START_STICKY).

So, if it's not started inside a separate process, there should be at least one process where the service can run. So, is it possible that a service runs even if there are no processes? I repeat, the service (from manifest) HASN'T GOT the directive android: background

**EDIT 1:**
It seems that it is a bug of Android 4.4.2. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63618). In my case I encounter the problem when I swipe the app from the list (as described in second link)

**EDIT 2:**
Please correct me if I'm wrong, this is what I've understood.

A `Service` object is created for the first time when `startService()` is called. `onCreate()` will be called on that Service object and `onStartCommand()` will follow. From now on:

- If the process dies, the service object is still there (if `stopSelf()`
  is not called) but it isn't running.
- If the service dies, the only way to be recreated is from `START_STICKY` (and other restart constants) or manual call to startService(). When the service is killed from the system, onCreate will be called again.

Now, this is the normal behavior on Android < 4.4.2. On KitKat, if you swipe the application from the LRU list, the process dies and even with START_STICKY it is not automatically restarted. Workaround is an AlarmManager. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service is part of your application.  By definition, your application is running when the Service is running.  When, for instance, the AlarmManager invokes your Service at a scheduled time, Android first starts a process for the application (if it is not already running), and then invokes your Service within the now running app.

In general, you are correct: If the application (process) dies, the Service will die with it.

Android supports a Manifest attribute, `android:process`, which allows you to specify that a particular component of your application should be run in a separate process.  This, essentially, runs multiple, identical, copies of your application, in multiple processes.  Android simply uses one of the processes to run one component and another to run the other.  Your application is running in both.

The source of confusion is the way Settings > Apps page uses the words "process" and "service".  It appears to use the former to count processes with UI components and the latter to count all other processes.  If you use adb to connect to your device and use the "ps" command you'll get something that much better reflects the common understanding of those words.

Comment: Thank you. So the word "process" used in settings means "the process that has got UI"? It's weird, because it seems (from the manifest) that that particular Service has not declared to run in a separate process by using andoird:process. Are there any sources where it talks about the difference between process and service (in the Settings tab?). Thanks again

Comment: I've poked around a bit, and I take that part back.  I cannot figure out what those two numbers are, at all. :-(  The number labelled "service" does seem to be the count of services running in the process.  I cannot figure out what "process" means, at all.  An entry in the Settings > Apps > Running list corresponds to the normal meaning of the word "process", a Linux process.

Answer (score 0):

The Main problem with some of the android operating system is when app closed then android OS(**In Some OS**) will kill the service, If you are not able to restart the service then call a alarm manger to start the reciver like this,

Manifest is,

```
         <service
            android:name=".BackgroundService"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="Notification" />
        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="REFRESH_THIS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

IN Main Activty start alarm manger in this way,

```
String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(alarm);

        Intent intent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 123456789, intent, 0);

        int type = AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP;
        long interval = 1000 * 50;

        am.setInexactRepeating(type, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pi);
```

this will call reciver and reciver is,

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        System.out.println("Alarma Reciver Called");

        if (isMyServiceRunning(this.context, BackgroundService.class)) {
            System.out.println("alredy running no need to start again");
        } else {
            Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
            context.startService(background);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        if (services != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
                if ((serviceClass.getName()).equals(services.get(i).service.getClassName()) && services.get(i).pid != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this Alaram reciver calls once when android app is opened and when app is closed.SO the service is like this,

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private String LOG_TAG = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LOG_TAG = "app_name";
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "service created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onStartCommand");
        //ur actual code
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Wont be called as service is not bound
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onTaskRemoved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroyed");
    }
}
```